# Регистрация через facebook ionic

Tags: facebook-api, auth, ionic

Все сделал по [данному](https://ccoenraets.github.io/ionic-tutorial/ionic-facebook-integration.html) туториалу. На сервере происходит открытие окна авторизации, а на эмуляторе выдает такое окно:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В чем может быть ошибка?

Answer (score 2):

Ошибка была в том, что не добавил в Valid OAuth redirect URIs строку:

```
https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html
```